# Is normal this code run SOO slow?

Tags: c, performance, execution

look at my code , it is running slow as a turtle, i running it under a forth generation i7... and it is realy slow to show off the result. does anybody have one ideia? or this should be a very slow execution!?

PS: the prourpose of the script is to find greatest product of four adjacent numbers in the same direction, actualy in this code i'm looking only for the up one

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(){

        int A[20][20] = {
        {8,02,22,97,38,15,00,40,00,75,04,05,07,78,52,12,50,77,91,8},
        {49,49,99,40,17,81,18,57,60,87,17,40,98,43,69,48,04,56,62,00},
        {81,49,31,73,55,79,14,29,93,71,40,67,53,88,30,03,49,13,36,65},
        {52,70,95,23,04,60,11,42,69,24,68,56,01,32,56,71,37,02,36,91},
        {22,31,16,71,51,67,63,89,41,92,36,54,22,40,40,28,66,33,13,80},
        {24,47,32,60,99,03,45,02,44,75,33,53,78,36,84,20,35,17,12,50},
        {32,98,81,28,64,23,67,10,26,38,40,67,59,54,70,66,18,38,64,70},
        {67,26,20,68,02,62,12,20,95,63,94,39,63,8,40,91,66,49,94,21},
        {24,55,58,05,66,73,99,26,97,17,78,78,96,83,14,88,34,89,63,72},
        {21,36,23,9,75,00,76,44,20,45,35,14,00,61,33,97,34,31,33,95},
        {78,17,53,28,22,75,31,67,15,94,03,80,04,62,16,14,9,53,56,92},
        {16,39,05,42,96,35,31,47,55,58,88,24,00,17,54,24,36,29,85,57},
        {86,56,00,48,35,71,89,07,05,44,44,37,44,60,21,58,51,54,17,58},
        {19,80,81,68,05,94,47,69,28,73,92,13,86,52,17,77,04,89,55,40},
        {04,52,8,83,97,35,99,16,07,97,57,32,16,26,26,79,33,27,98,66},
        {88,36,68,87,57,62,20,72,03,46,33,67,46,55,12,32,63,93,53,69},
        {04,42,16,73,38,25,39,11,24,94,72,18,8,46,29,32,40,62,76,36},
        {20,69,36,41,72,30,23,88,34,62,99,69,82,67,59,85,74,04,36,16},
        {20,73,35,29,78,31,90,01,74,31,49,71,48,86,81,16,23,57,05,54},
        {01,70,54,71,83,51,54,69,16,92,33,48,61,43,52,01,89,19,67,48}};

        int x = 0 ,y = 0, radar_x = 0,radar_y = 0,maior = 0,produto = 1;


        while(x<=19){
                while(y<=19){
                        printf("%d %d \n",x,y);
                        // verredura pra cima
                        if(x - 3 >= 0){
                                radar_x = x-3;
                                while(radar_x >= x-3){
                                        produto*=A[x][y];
                                        radar_x ++ ;
                                }

                        }
                        if(produto > maior)
                                maior = produto;
                        produto = 1;
                        y++;
                }
                y=0;
                x++;
        }

        printf("%d",maior);


        return 0;

}
```

Comment: Three nested while loops is probably one of the reasons.

Comment: I don't understand how `while(radar_x >= x-3){` can exit, if `x` is not modified and `radar_x` is only incremented? Unless you wait for an int overflow, which indeed can take quite some time.

Comment: Well, how 'slow' is it? How long exactly does it take to execute? Why do you expect it to run faster than it actually does?

Comment: It's probably running quite fast but there are a lot of iterations to do... 16 * 19 * "infinite" iterations of the `while(radar_x >= x-3)` loop.

Comment: Additionaly, the output itself could be a bottleneck.

Comment: I think by `while (radar_x >= x-3)` you mean `while (radar_x <= x)`.

Comment: There exist profilers.

Comment: Codor , its taking too much time, like, i started it 10 minutes ago , and it dont finished yet.

Comment: o yeah.. the problem maybe is the radar_x thing, i wil chack that guys, thanks a lot !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason it hasn't finished yet is because it will never technically stop. The third while loop is set to increment `radar_x` forever, with no upper bound. It's an easy mistake to make.

Just change it to `while (radar_x <= x)` to fix the problem.

Comment: Works !! Thanks a lot you and the others who helped!

Answer (score 2):

Examining the inner for loop (written as a while) :

```
radar_x = x-3;
while(radar_x >= x-3){
    produto*=A[x][y];
    radar_x ++ ;
}
```

radar_x >= x-3 is true first time.. then radar_x is incremented... so this will likely loop until overflow occurs incrementing INT32_MAX              (2147483647), when radar_x is suddenly < 0

You're looping at least 2 billion times, every time you start doing the multiplications.

The actual behaviour is underfined, a compiler writer is within their rights to say "the program is not C", so if you may overflow any adition should test "a < MAXINT - b" before executing a += b

Comment: And signed integer overflow is undefined behavior, the optimizer may just eliminate the condition entirely, making a true infinite loop.

Comment: Yes, in theory the compiler can do anything; a reason not to turn an optimiser on until you are confident, the program is correct.  It could decide, that it'd be faster not to loop at all and skip that part, taking advantage of "undefined behaviour".

Comment: The info "it is realy slow to show off the result" suggested it does terminate, so I thought I'd explain why it's slow.  By time I posted, there were already 2 other answers!

Comment: The comment 6 minutes before your answer says "still running".  So no idea whether it ever terminates.

Comment: But I was answering the question.. the comments were written later :)  Not really important, integers going -ve tend to happen (slowly) on such errors ..  Once I saw a bug on 64bit on an NTP time daemon port, it showed up because it took excruciatingly long to overflow

Answer (score 0):

This part of your code,

```
radar_x = x-3;
while(radar_x >= x-3){
   produto*=A[x][y];
   radar_x ++ ;
}
```

results in a quite long loop (possibly infinite, possibly undefined, possibly depending on your compiler), as `x` is not modified and `radar_x` is only incremented

To get the product of the 4 items in `[x - 3, x]`, I would probably more simply do:

```
for (int radar_x = 0; radar_x < 4; radar_x++) {
    produto*=A[x - radar_x][y];
}
```

### Edit

Remove already given answer, leave only alternative for loop

Comment: Yeah, I saw the ninja edit where you reversed the comparison according to architect's answer (and Charles's comment)...

Comment: Yes, I am a ninja. I didn't quite paid much attention to that loop (i'll probably just remove it). I prefer the `for` one, for clarity.

Comment: @BenVoigt: what's with charles' comment?

Comment: ninja edits are allowed and encouraged, as long as you eventually arrive at the correct answer. I agree that OP needs to learn how to write `for` loops.

Comment: You can't really say the loop is not infinite. What if it runs on a processor with saturating arithmetic? Signed overflow is not defined.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Ok, I would have though that in most cases it simply either crashes or goes back to negative values.